# Building correct classes

Tags: c++, string, class, unix

I want to get the full content of a text file receive for example on av[1] and put it on a string variable
here is the classes ive made

map_stuff.hpp

```
class Map
{
public:
  Map(std::string dat_av);
  ~Map();

  std::string   get_map(std::string dat_avv);
};
```

and map_stuff.cpp

```
std::string Map::get_map()
{
  std::string   conv_map;

  return(conv_map);
}
```

while compiling I got this error

map_stuff.cpp:7:13: error: prototype for ‘std::string Map::get_map()’ does not match any in class ‘Map’
map_stuff.hpp:15:15: error: candidate is: std::string Map::get_map(std::string)

Im kind of new to c++ im from C what im doing wrong and is this the good way ?

Comment: Does the error message not say it? Those two functions don't have the same signature.

Comment: that being said have you learned about `const` and references

Comment: I could use const but its only for smaller ressources usage, no ?

Comment: @Saxtheowl About const: citing from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv): _an object whose type is const-qualified, or a non-mutable subobject of a const object. Such object cannot be modified: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, and attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined behavior._

Comment: So its a security thing, okay lets do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header you have:

```
std::string get_map(std::string dat_avv);
```

but in the cpp you have

```
std::string Map::get_map()
```

They're not the same, but they should be, so either remove the argument from the header, or add it to the implementation.